# Dropdown inside table cell toggles table row height on every click

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down inside a table cell. On a click, the dropdown expands to show the menu items. But, the table row height also changes whenever the menu expands/collapses.

How can i keep the table row height constant and the dropdown gets displayed over the table. I tried setting higher z-index for dropdown container but it didn't work. As,

```
.menu-body{
    background-color: #ea7600;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Plunker code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/whqttI7DAThlmZEtOLKW?p=preview).

[image]

Table height must not fall below the second dark horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use absolute positioning, but that requires some minor html changes as well:

add span to th and td:

```
<th><span>lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng header</span></th>

<td><span>lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng content</span></td>
```

change css:

```
 td,th{
   position: relative;
   border: solid black 2px;
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: center;
 }

  td span,th span{
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow : hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: block;
  }

.menu-body{
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Updates plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WYyrnO5lIVFFJBCNdfNc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent-container-classname *{
 overflow : visible;
}

.menu-body{
 overflow : auto !important;
}
```

all parent containers should have `overflow:visible` and your drop down should have `overflow:auto`